# Cursor starting issue in Android layout activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-designer

I know it maybe looks a simple question but it really annoying me, I have an Activity contains 3 "EditText", and when I lunch that activity it the cursor start in second one "EditText", what I want is starting the cursor on the "EditText" I choose for example first "EditText".

Note: I'm using Activity contains Scrollview and Constraint layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<requestFocus>` in the XML of the EditText you want to have initial focus. See [Layout Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @AhmedSaid No problem. You may also want to familiarize yourself with the XML tag `nextFocusForward` to make sure you proceed through your layout in the order you want. Android does a pretty good job at guessing the right order, but sometime it's a little off.

Comment: Yest you are right too,Android documentation is pretty clear. Thanks :)))

Answer (score 1):

**Programmatically:**

```
edittext.requestFocus();
```

**Through XML:**

```
<EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Or call onClick method manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.